# Coherence clustering configuration

Tags: oracle-coherence

I am new to oracle coherence and trying out a POC to use coherence as a distributed cache for our application. This is in my dev environment, I am trying to have a clustered setup with two coherence client instances.
The changes I did was to create `tangosol_coherence_override.xml` and `coherence-cache-config.xml`
Below are the details present.

As suggested in the user guide when i start one instance of default cache server and two instances of coherence, they are not clustered, changes made on console on one coherence does not reflect on the other.

The changes I did was to set a unicast address and port, configure the cluster name and port.
Any pointers or sample configuration files would help.
My machine ip - 10.209.14.17

**tangosol_coherence_override.xml**

```xml
<?xml version='1.0'?>

   <coherence  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
            xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/coherence/coherence-operational-config"
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.oracle.com/coherence/coherence-operational-config coherence-operational-config.xsd">

   <cluster-config>
      <member-identity>
         <cluster-name system-property="tangosol.coherence.cluster">GR</cluster-name>
      </member-identity>


      <unicast-listener>
         <address system-property="tangosol.coherence.localhost">10.209.14.17
         </address>
         <port system-property="tangosol.coherence.localport">8090</port>
         <port-auto-adjust system-property="tangosol.coherence.localport.adjust">
            true
         </port-auto-adjust>
      </unicast-listener>
    <multicast-listener>
         <address>224.3.7.0</address>
         <port>4280</port>
         <time-to-live>0</time-to-live>
      </multicast-listener>
   </cluster-config>

   <configurable-cache-factory-config>
      <init-params>
         <init-param>
            <param-type>java.lang.String</param-type>
            <param-value system-property="tangosol.coherence.cacheconfig">
               coherence-cache-config.xml</param-value>
         </init-param>
      </init-params>
   </configurable-cache-factory-config>
</coherence>
```

**coherence-cache-config.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<cache-config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/coherence/coherence-cache-config"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.oracle.com/coherence/coherence-cache-config
   coherence-cache-config.xsd">
   <caching-scheme-mapping>
      <cache-mapping>
         <cache-name>voCache</cache-name>
         <scheme-name>distributed</scheme-name>
      </cache-mapping>
   </caching-scheme-mapping>

   <caching-schemes>
      <distributed-scheme>
         <scheme-name>distributed</scheme-name>
         <service-name>DistributedCache</service-name>
         <backing-map-scheme>
            <local-scheme/>
         </backing-map-scheme>
         <autostart>true</autostart>
      </distributed-scheme>
   </caching-schemes>
</cache-config>
```

Comment: I could solve this problem after further analysis, multicast was not enabled for my network. I could verify it using the multicasttest script provided as part of coherence. So I instead added WKA within the unicast Listener and then the cache instances started joining the same cluster.

Comment: FYI, Stack Overflow allows you to provide an answer for your own question, if you think it would be helpful to others.  Just type or paste your answer in the box at the bottom, and click "Post Your Answer".

Answer (score 1):

Perform a Coherence multicast test as per the documentation:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18686_01/coh.37/e18679/tune_multigramtest.htm

If multicast is disabled, use WKA:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18686_01/coh.37/e18677/cluster_setup.htm#CEGEADBE