# How to limit coherence broadcastsing to certain hosts?

Tags: oracle-coherence

I use Welogic 12c and Coherence? coherehce cache broadcast to every coherence node on the network? how to limit broadcasting to certain addresses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use WKA for discovery to eliminate multicast from discovery.

You can also disable multicast altogether for communication. Coherence does not require multicast.

Answer (score 2):

you should use Well-Known Addresses (WKA) feature instead of multicast option.
See answer to the similar question  [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6277820/coherence-clustering-configuration)

12c documentation [Here](http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/wls/CLUST/coherence.htm#CLUST638)

Comment: I found that WKA is for development not production use:
"The system assigned WKA member feature is only designed for testing and development on a single server and can result in port conflicts, because ports are chosen using an offset algorithm"
check  https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/wls/CLUST/coherence.htm#CLUST663"

Comment: I believe it says that you should explicitly choose WKA instead of rely on automatic assignment of ports.

Comment: Documentation has lots of information about configuration files, but what is the location of these files? default configuration  located in coherence.jar I don't these files meant to be modifed

Comment: I recommend you to read https://blogs.oracle.com/felcey/entry/coherence_clustering_principles